# How do I access both a parent and child JSON record, if the parent is not the highest element?

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to load the SQuAD dataset using Pandas. The JSON elements in my dataset are structured like this, where everything that ends in "s" represents a list:

```
-data
-- title
-- paragraphs
-- context
--- qas
---- id
---- question
----- answers
------ answerStart
------ answerText
```

I want to create a DataFrame that looks something like this:

question title context answerText

However, I only want just one "answerText" value per question, so that means only one answer per "qas" field. Since "qas" has an id that is unique to each pair, it may be best to create an "answers" dataframe, then another dataframe that looks like this:

qas_id answer_id

However, I'm not quite sure how to best set this schema up. Here's what I have tried:

```
with open(filename) as file:
    data = json.load(file)["data"]
    questions = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data,record_path=["paragraphs","qas","question"],meta=["paragraphs","qas","id"])
    answers = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data,record_path=["paragraphs","qas","answers"],meta=["paragraphs","qas","id"])
```

Since meta apparently only allows access to the children of the top element, how do I create a dataframe with both the "id" element of "qas" and the "answerStart" and "answerText" elements of answers?

Comment: Could you post some example data (i.e., a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))? The JSON schema alone is not enough to experiment with answers.

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler: Sure, what's the best way to do that? Tree view? Link to a smaller JSON file?

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler: Here's a smaller JSON file: https://github.com/moonman239/Capstone-project/blob/master/test-json.json

Comment: finally got a chance to look at this. The JSON standard requires double quotes (`"`), not single quotes (`'`), and the JSON snippet you linked to is corrupted by unescaped single and double quotes throughout the text. Could you reformat and re-upload?

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler: This file might do, but please note that I was unable to reproduce the problem I am having with my code: https://github.com/moonman239/Capstone-project/blob/master/train-v1.1-test.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have a working solution:

```
import json
import re
import string
import pandas as pd
def readFile(filename):
    with open(filename) as file:
        data = json.load(file)["data"]
        qas = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data,record_path=["paragraphs","qas"],meta=["title"])
        #print(qas["question"])
        #Gather a list of where all answers should be so we can shove them into a DataFrame.
        # Haven't found a more efficient way to do this yet.
        answer_ids = set()
        answerId = 0
        for index,row in qas.iterrows():
            answer_ids.add(answerId)
            answerId = answerId + len(row["answers"])
        print("Finished with answer ids.")
        # Map qas pair IDs to answer IDs.
        answer_ids = pd.DataFrame(list(answer_ids))
        print("Finished converting answer_ids to DataFrame.")
        question_answerId = pd.DataFrame(qas["question"]).join(answer_ids,how="outer")
        question_answerId.columns = ["question","answer_id"]
        #print("Id-answerID columns: ",id_answerId.columns)
        print("finished creating intermediary table.")
        # Load answers into a data frame.
        answers = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data,record_path=["paragraphs","qas","answers"])
        answers.rename(columns={"text":"answer_text"},inplace=True)
        # Give each answer an ID.
        answers["id"] = answers.index
        print("Finished creating answers dataframe.")
        qas = qas.drop(labels=["answers"],axis=1) # Not needed any longer; we have the answers!
        #print("Dropped column 'answers' from qas.")
        # Map qas dataframe to answer table via id_answerId
        qas_answerId = pd.merge(qas,question_answerId,how="inner",on="question")
        # Check that no duplicates exist in qas_answerId
        qas_answerId = qas_answerId.drop_duplicates("question")
        assert qas_answerId.duplicated("question").any() == False
        print("Finished joining qas to answer id")
        # Merge qas_answerId with answers.
        returnDataFrame = pd.merge(qas_answerId,answers,how="inner",left_on="answer_id",right_on="id")
        #print("Returned data frame: ",returnDataFrame)
        print("Done!")
        return returnDataFrame
```